# Rich snippets Only showing in site query and not in normal search

Tags: google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented review schema.org rich snippets in my website. When i check them with site query, they appears. But when i search my results in google normally, they don't. Google rich snippets tool also identify all the markups i placed. Why google not showing it in normal search? And how to display it in normal search?

Answer (score 3):

As you already detected that the rich snippet for you page *does* get displayed, it’s very likely no problem with your markup (otherwise it would *never* get displayed).

If a page is eligible for a rich snippet, it doesn’t mean that it will be displayed for all queries. Google Search decides for which queries they display which rich snippets. There doesn’t seem to be a way to control or do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used a wordpress plugin for rich snippet and i was surprised that google started showing rich snippets in normal search result. Only difference i was able to find between my implementation and plugin's implementation was that i was showing few of my values in meta tags which were not visible on page to audience but only to google but that plugin was showing  all the values on screen to users. That's the difference i think would be.